# Eigen-decomposition of real Symmetric psd matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, singular-values

I am doing PCA analysis on a large amount of data and I need to compute the eigen-decomposition of the covariance matrix which is a real, symmetric, positive semi definite matrix. It doesn't get any simpler than that!

I want to compute this myself from first principles and not using some matlab, mathematica or whatever package. That's an infinite process but I am looking for a fast and robust method. Can anyone post an algorithm for it? I did a web search and found several methods but nothing complete and from scratch.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You will find answer to it and many others in a best seller, very often cited in scientific papers: "Matrix Computations" by Golub and Van Loan. I know that listing books may lead to an endless dangerous chat, but this book is special ...

Comment: I want to reinvent a wheel but have no idea what a wheel looks like, can you post one? I'm impressed by your resolute denial of computer codes people worked on for decades, sir.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Sometimes, when you are doing research, you are not only interested in the functionality of a program, but you want to deeply understand it. And sometimes, the benefit of such a deep understanding of a given function appear a long time after, in an unexpected way.

Comment: @Damien I understand that what you say might be happening but the question does not give me an impression that this is the case.

Comment: @Damien Thanks! It's quite involved with bidiagonal matrices and so on but it looks like I can't do any better...